# How to prevent repaint of other elements when using CSS transition

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms, repaint

I am trying to prevent browser repainting to improve performance on a large single page app that makes use of CSS animations.

If I have an element that has a `:hover { transform: scale(...) }` effect on it, I can prevent repaints by using the `will-change: transform` and/or `transform: translateZ(0)` as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas).

But as soon as I add a `transition` to that element, many elements start being repainted again.

Here is a [demo codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzKBdK) and a gif of it[image]

The only thing that worked to prevent this repaint is to put the other elements before the animating element in the DOM order, or to z-index the animating element above the other elements. But with a complex single-page app, I do not want to have to micromanage the z-index of any element that just wants a hover transition.

Any other ideas or references? I haven't seen this specific problem with `transition`s discussed elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

It seemed like the `position: absolute;` on `.other` was not creating a new layer, I was able to solve the issue by adding `transform: translateZ(0)` to the `.other` class.

[JSbin](https://output.jsbin.com/sujisusama/)

Given that you're working on a SPA, i'm not sure how feasible this approach is, since there could be hundreds of elements after the circle.